# Blender 2.93 stops recognizing my graphics card (Nvidia RTX 2060) every few hours. Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers

I keep having to restart my pc in order to get blender to use my graphics card (NVidia RTX 2060).  It works great until it doesn't.  I refresh a screen in render mode and there's just nothing there.  switching to CPU works.  Then I restart PC and everything is back to normal.  I'm using Ubuntu 21.04, I don't seem to have any other problems although when I tried to use Optix once it did freeze my pc (mouse having a nervous breakdown in the corner and only partially responsive.).

Comment: Are you using Blender Snap or from the official website? also make sure your drivers are correctly and using Nvidia  proprietary drivers

Comment: I downloaded from the blender site, not sure what snap is.  I think I am correctly using the proprietary drivers, how would I know if I’m not?

Comment: A snap is a software package, you could download the snap version using the Ubuntu software (it's like an app store). For your drivers, I think you might need to get some help over some Ubuntu forums for a better answer, but basically, you need to go to the "Software and update" app and check what driver are you using in the "Additional Drivers" section

Comment: hmm, I am using the latest proprietary nvidia driver for my gpu.  I'll check out the ubuntu forums though, thank you.